# How does one declare a variable of type returned by getParameterTypes()?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I want to declare a variable that is of the of the type returned by getParameterTypes(), but I get an error.  I also get the same error for getTypeParameters() "cannot be resolved to a type."
How can this be done?

```
  Class<?> lcSeqHolder = null;
  TypeVariable<Method> lcTypeHolder = null;

  // Use reflection to find the take method
  Method[] lcMethods = mcSpecificReader.getDeclaredMethods();
  for (Method lcMethod : lcMethods)
  {
     System.out.println(lcMethod.getName());
     if (lcMethod.getName().equals(TAKE_METHOD_NAME))
     {
        lcSeqHolder = lcMethod.getParameterTypes()[SEQUENCE_HOLDER_ARG_INDEX];
        lcTypeHolder = lcMethod.getTypeParameters()[SEQUENCE_HOLDER_ARG_INDEX];

        lcSeqHolder  var1;  // <-- lcSeqHolder cannot be resolved to a type
        lcTypeHolder  var2; // <-- lcTypeHolder cannot be resolved to a type
     }
  }
```

Comment: Do you know possible values for types returned by `lcMethod.getParameterTypes()` and `lcMethod.getTypeParameters`? Do you have to import classes or are they of types like `String` or `Integer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need an object on the type lcSeqHolder? Try this:

```
Object var1 = lcSeqHolder.newInstance();
```

It will only work if the class defined by lcSeqHolder has a default constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You can't, and almost certainly don't need to. A variable's type needs to be known at *compile-time*, and clearly you don't know it.

Most of the time, you should just declare the variables to be of type `Object` - that's all you really know about them, after all. If you *do* know more (for some reason), declare them with whatever you know (e.g. some interface) and cast appropriately.

Assuming you don't have any more information, you wouldn't be able to *use* the more specific types anyway - so what would you hope to gain from declaring the variable to be of a particular type?

Answer (score 0):

All classes extend Object.  You can make that the type.